# Regex Problem Group Name Redefinition?

Tags: python, regex

So I have this regex:

```
(^(\s+)?(?P<NAME>(\w)(\d{7}))((01f\.foo)|(\.bar|\.goo\.moo\.roo))$|(^(\s+)?(?P<NAME2>R1_\d{6}_\d{6}_)((01f\.foo)|(\.bar|\.goo\.moo\.roo))$))
```

Now if I try and do a match against this:

```
B048661501f.foo
```

I get this error:

```
  File "C:\Python25\lib\re.py", line 188, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\re.py", line 241, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: redefinition of group name 'NAME' as group 9; was group 3
```

If I can't define the same group twice in the same regex expression for two different cases, what do I do?

Comment: Works for me. Returned; ('B048661501f.foo', None, 'B0486615', 'B', '0486615', '01f.foo', '01f.foo', None, None, None, None, None, None, None)

Comment: You have waaaaaaaay too many parentheses in your regex. Taking the unnecessary ones out alone would make it considerably shorter.

Comment: @muhuk Makes sense. There is only one group named `NAME` and one group named `NAME2`. Obviously the regex in the question is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't have two groups of the same name, this would somehow defy the purpose, wouldn't it?

What you probably *really* want is this:

```
^\s*(?P<NAME>\w\d{7}|R1_(?:\d{6}_){2})(01f\.foo|\.(?:bar|goo|moo|roo))$
```

I refactored your regex as far as possible. I made the following assumptions:

You want to (correct me if I'm wrong):

- ignore white space at the start of the string
- match either of the following into a group named "NAME":

  - a letter followed by 7 digits, or
  - `"R1_"`, and two times (6 digits + `"_"`)
- followed by either:

  - `"01f.foo"` or
  - `"."` and (`"bar"` or `"goo"` or `"moo"` or `"roo"`)
- followed by the end of the string

---

You could also have meant:

```
^\s*(?P<NAME>\w\d{7}01f|R1_(?:\d{6}_){2})\.(?:foo|bar|goo|moo|roo)$
```

Which is:

- ignore white space at the start of the string
- match either of the following into a group named "NAME":

  - a letter followed by 7 digits and "01f"
  - `"R1_"`, and two times (6 digits + `"_"`)
- a dot
- `"foo"`, `"bar"`, `"goo"`, `"moo"` or `"roo"`
- the end of the string

Comment: Multiple named capturing groups with the same name is a very useful feature.  Python doesn't support it, but .NET does.

Comment: Nice to know, I would have been too strict to even try/consider it.

Comment: It seems duplicate named capture groups works in the `regex` package but not `re`

Answer (score 9):

Reusing the same name makes sense in your case, contrary to Tamalak's reply.

Your regex compiles with python2.7 and also re2. Maybe this problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

The following answer deals with how to make the above regex work in Python3.

Since the re2 module as suggested by Max would not work in Python3, because of the
`NameError: basestring`. Another alternative to this is the `regex` module.

`regex` module is just an enhanced version of `re` with extra added features. This
module also allows to have same group names in the regex.

You can install it via:

```
sudo pip install regex
```

And if you have already been using `re` or `re2` in your program. Just do the following to import `regex` module

```
import regex as re
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44463324/416988), Python PyPi `regex` module supports a *branch reset feature*.