# How can I make future captures depend on an earlier match in python regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse messages of the following format using regular expression:

- `/log/<sender>`
- `/error/<sender>`
- `/state/<sender>/<variable_name>`

I would like to be able to retreive the type of message, the sender of the message and if the message is a `state` message the variable name. Note that log and error messages cannot include a variable name under this schema.

I tried doing this with the following pattern:

```
address_pattern = re.compile(
    r'''/
       ((?P<type> log)/(?P<sender> [^/]*))
     | ((?P<type> error)/(?P<sender> [^/]*))
     | ((?P<type> state)/(?P<sender> [^/]*)/(?P<parameter> [^/]*))
    ''', re.VERBOSE)
```

However, this is not a valid pattern because the capture groups `<type>` and `<sender>` are defined multiple times (although logically only one will match).

Is there a single regex that can parse this string for me and provide the three matches?

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
r'/(?P<type>log|error|state)/(?P<sender>[^/]+)(?:/(?P<parameter>[^/]+))?'
```

?

You can check the semantics after and throw an error if people try stuff like `/error/<sender>/<variable>`.

Regular Expressions are limited. By definition, they do not allow you to take decisions later on based on previous matches. Some syntaxes (such as Python's) let you cheat and re-use a previous match. e.g. `r'<(a|p|div)></\1>'`, but that's as far as you can go. Otherwise, you're  limited to a [DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automata).

Comment: Thank you, that solves my problem. Though I am still curious to know if it's possible to do both capture and validation with a single regex.

Comment: Being finite automata, RegEx cannot do this kind of operation. At most, you can recover a previous match and use it later, like `r'<(a|p|div)></\1>'`. But that's already "cheating", since theoretically a regular expression should have no "memory".

Comment: But would the pattern in the question not work were it not for the fact that the group names cannot be repeated?

Comment: @TimMB I don't understand the question, sorry, can you rephrase it?

Comment: Yeah sorry that wasn't very clear! I mean - from a matching perspective, there isn't any need for the expression to have memory. We just match r'(/log/[^/]+)|(/error/[^]+)|(/state/[^/]+/[^/]+)'. The first log/error/state determines the format of the remainder of the message. The difficulty comes with capture, and only because I want to use the same group name for different elements in the regex. So to me it seems the finite automata restrictions on regex are not the reason this is possible - it is the implementation of capturing.

Comment: Ah OK, got it. I think this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363171/regex-problem-group-name-redefinition

Comment: Thanks - this comment from Jan Goyvaerts sums it up: Multiple named capturing groups with the same name is a very useful feature. Python doesn't support it, but .NET does. However, I've found a slightly more compact solution than error checking - will post.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that isn't 100% regex but behaves equivalently:

For a string `s` you have

```
state_pat = re.compile(r'/(?P<type>state)/(?P<sender>[^/]+)/(?P<parameter>[^/]+)')
log_pat = re.compile(r'/(?P<type>(log|warning|error))/(?P<sender>[^/]+)')
ping_pat = re.compile(r'/(?P<type>ping)/(?P<sender>[^/]+)')

match = state_pat.match(s) or log_pat.match(s) or ping_pat.match(s)
```

Essentially, partition each logical requiring reuse of a group name into its own pattern and then use the short-circuiting of `or` to return the first one that matches. You can then use `match.group('type')` to test which pattern matched and the behaviour is as expected in the original question.

Likewise, strings such as `/log/sender/parameter` will not match and you'll be returned `None`.