# How can I find two different items using one regex without empty results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am looking for two different things:

```
import re
s = """
PUT_abc(false);
def=123;
PUT_fed(true);
PUT_hfe(def==(uint8)15);"""

print(re.findall(r'(?:^PUT_(\w*)\((.*)\);|^(\w+)=(\w*);)', s, re.M))
```

It finds all results. But the result is:

```
[('abc', 'false', '', ''), ('', '', 'def', '123'), ('fed', 'true', '', ''), ('hfe', 'def==(uint8)15', '', '')]
```

Instead of the desired:

```
[('abc', 'false'), ('def', '123'), ('fed', 'true'), ('hfe', 'def==(uint8)15')]
```

How can I prevent the regex returning Match 3 and 4 instead MAtch 1 and 2 each time?

Comment: You can't. Every capture group is returned separately.

Comment: But it is an OR. Should not the (number of the) capture groups be also included in the OR?

Comment: Alternatives don't affect capture groups. This is actually useful, so you can tell which of the alternatives was matched.

Comment: It would also get very confusing if you had nested alternatives with capture groups. You wouldn't know what each of the returned results represents.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44463324/3832970, you need PyPi regex module and *branch reset group*.