# Regex have result in one group when pattern have several options inside

Tags: regex

I am parsing a string with bundle configurations.
For simplicity sake, let's say there are only two layouts:

```
WEIGHT*SIZE
and
SIZE*WEIGHT
```

sample data looks like this:

```
12g*15
13g*20
20pack*2.5kg
40packs*15g
10p*35g
```

Regex I am using now is basically two regex expressions for each layout divided by '|':

```
(?:[0-9]{1,3})(?:packs|pack|p|)\*([\d.,]{1,3})(?:g|kg)|([\d.,]{1,3})(?:g|kg)\*(?:[0-9]{1,3})(?:packs|pack|p|)
```

But in first two lines it gives result in group(1), and for later 3 result is in group(2).

For the simplicity sake, **can I somehow have result only in group(1) regardless which side of "|" in my regex fired?** So I don't need to iterate through groups after using re.search?

(I know i could just do `([\d.]{1,3})(?:g|kg)`, but I need to fetch weight form exactly this types of layouts, single weight without bundle size like `5kg` should not be taken into account)

Comment: Actually, on Python you can just use a single line if expression to choose the non empty capture group.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you please hint which one?

Comment: You may want to post your relevant Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify which language/flavour of RegEx you are using, but assuming you are using Python here are a few possible solutions:

### Option 1: Select first non-empty capturing group

This is the solution proposed in the comment from Tim Biegeleisen, and probably the quickest. Might look something like this:

```
import re
pattern = '(?:[0-9]{1,3})(?:packs|pack|p|)\*([\d.,]{1,3})(?:g|kg)|([\d.,]{1,3})(?:g|kg)\*(?:[0-9]{1,3})(?:packs|pack|p|)'
examples = "12g*15,13g*20,20pack*2.5kg,40packs*15g,10p*35g".split(',')

rx = re.compile(pattern)
for e in examples:
    for match in rx.finditer(e):
        for g in match.groups():
            if g:
                print(g)
```

Output:

```
12
13
2.5
15
35
```

### Option 2: Use named capturing groups

The syntax is `(?P<name>regex)` as per [this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refext.html). RegEx allows the same name for two capturing groups, so you could modify your RegEx to the following:

`(?:[0-9]{1,3})(?:packs|pack|p|)\*(?P<weight>[\d.,]{1,3})(?:g|kg)|(?P<weight>[\d.,]{1,3})(?:g|kg)\*(?:[0-9]{1,3})(?:packs|pack|p|)`

However, Python's in-built `re` module does not supported identically named groups (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460642/python-regex-duplicate-names-in-named-groups)), so you would need to pip install and import the PyPI `regex` module. Might look like this:

```
import regex
pattern = r'(?:[0-9]{1,3})(?:packs|pack|p|)\*(?P<weight>[\d.,]{1,3})(?:g|kg)|(?P<weight>[\d.,]{1,3})(?:g|kg)\*(?:[0-9]{1,3})(?:packs|pack|p|)'
examples = "12g*15,13g*20,20pack*2.5kg,40packs*15g,10p*35g".split(',')

rx = regex.compile(pattern)
for e in examples:
    for x in rx.finditer(e):
        print(x.group("weight"))
```

Output:

```
12
13
2.5
15
35
```

### Option 3: Rewrite the RegEx so that you can put both options inside a single named capturing group

You could make the parts before and after the weight optional so that you just have a single instance of the weight group:

`(?:(?:[0-9]{1,3})(?:packs|pack|p|)\*)?([\d.,]{1,3})(?:g|kg)(?:\*(?:[0-9]{1,3})(?:packs|pack|p|))?`

The above RegEx captures the number for the weight only in Group 1 for all of your examples. However it will also capture weights for a string like `40packs*15g*40packs` that doesn't match your initial spec. You should be able to rewrite it to be more strict while still keeping only a single capturing group, but it might end up getting quite long.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer!

Comment: Please edit your answer, in option 1 it should be `re.finditer(rx, e):`

Comment: Hi @Recently_Created_User, why? I believe the code runs as expected. This is the method Pattern.finditer (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.finditer), where Pattern is already compiled, as opposed to re.finditer (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.finditer) for uncompiled patterns.